# Orbi SRS60 satellite connecting to neighbor's Cable Modem, not broadcasting, but affecting network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem, netgear-router

I have an Orbi Pro SRS60 satellite that says it is not broadcasting, and when connected to my network, any computers on that wireless network show a "router" of 10.0.0.1, which appears to be my neighbor's cable modem.

What might be going on, and how might I try fixing it?

Background: After being away for a weekend, I came back to work to a really poor internet connection. I tried logging in to my cable modem, and found that my password didn't work. I looked in my Orbi Pro SRR60 admin web interface and saw some hardwired equipment to my SRS60 satellite that I didn't recognize. I noticed several devices connected to it all had a 10.0.0.X IP address, rather than the 192.168.1.X network the Orbi should have been on. I changed my cable modem, and factory reset all of my Orbis. Upon reconnecting them, I had the same issue. After removing the offending satellite, everything works as normal (except for devices outside of the range now that I only have one satellite).

What might be going on, and how might I try fixing it?

Comment: Have you gone over to your neighbor and asked if they're having network issues or made changes to their internet? Have you talked to your ISP?

Comment: I have talked to the neighbor and they said they did have issues recently, but they were resolved. I didn't think to ask about changes to their network. I spoke several times with ISP. Their take was I needed a new modem b/c mine was old. When I figured out that taking the one satellite out of service fixed the issue, I thought probably it's not worth talking to their support staff anymore, since it seemed to be an internal issue for me at that point.